# elementwise and on two pandas series

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to create a new Boolean column on a pandas `DataFrame` based on two conditions. The following errors:

```
df['new'] = df['old'] != 'A' & df['old'] != 'B'
```

with

> TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of
>   type [bool]

`and` and `&&` also error.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `df['new'] = (df['old'] != 'A') & (df['old'] != 'B')`

Comment: Or `df['new'] = ~df['old'].isin(['A', 'B'])` easier to maintain.

Comment: Or, `df['new'] = np.logical_and.reduce([df['old'] != v for v in ['A', 'B']])`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Thanks, your comment (and Zero's) answer my question but the 'duplicate' you linked to does not as the answer there is applying binary operators to entire `DataFrame`s in an index. The second answer doesn't contain the parenthesis which is what I was missing.

Comment: The point of the dupe was to show you how to work with multiple conditions...

Comment: You should put each part in parentheses: df['new'] = (df['old'] != 'A') & (df['old'] != 'B'). This will work.